# C#: PointF() Array Initializer

Tags: c#, arrays, array-initialize

I need to hard code an array of points in my C# program. The C-style initializer did not work.

```
PointF[] points = new PointF{
    /* what goes here? */
};
```

How is it done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
PointF[] points = new PointF[]{
    new PointF(0,0), new PointF(1,1)
};
```

In c# 3.0 you can write it even shorter:

```
PointF[] points = {
    new PointF(0,0), new PointF(1,1)
};
```

**update** Guffa pointed out that I was to short with the `var points`, it's indeed not possible to "implicitly typed variable with an array initializer".

Comment: And we don't even need the size! Just the brackets!!

Comment: I've checked it in the snippet compiler and changed my answer.

Comment: No, you can't use an implicitly typed variable with an array initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate each PointF with new.

Something like

Pointf[] points = { new PointF(0,0), new PointF(1,1), etc...

Syntax may not be 100% here... I'm reaching back to when I last had to do it years ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
PointF[] points = new PointF[]
{
    new PointF( 1.0f, 1.0f),
    new PointF( 5.0f, 5.0f)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For C# 3:

```
PointF[] points = {
   new PointF(1f, 1f),
   new PointF(2f, 2f)
};
```

For C# 2 (and 1):

```
PointF[] points = new PointF[] {
   new PointF(1f, 1f),
   new PointF(2f, 2f)
};
```